# Issue with the AWS SSO setup with the Gossamer3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sso, gossamer3

I am trying to setup AWS SSO using the [Gossamer3](https://github.com/GESkunkworks/gossamer3/releases) SSO tool with the default profile. When I did this for the first time, it worked fine. The connection to AWS was established in AWS CLI (using latest version: aws-cli/2.14.6). However, by default it sets up the expiry token for an hour and then I was unable to login again after an hour.

So, I deleted the `.aws` folder and `.gossamer3.yaml` file in the path `C:\Users\<user_id>` and tried to setup here again, which created the same folder and files. It's failing now to login to AWS from CLI.

```
gossamer3 configure
```

[image]

This configuration created a `.gossamer3.yaml` file in the user path.

[image]

Next when I try to login to AWS using gossamer3 as following, but It's failing.

```
gossamer3 login -a default
```

[image]

It created a folder `.aws` in user path.

[image]

credentials file content.

[image]

ERROR:

```
level=error msg="error logging into aws role using saml assertion: failed to create session: LoadCustomCABundleError: failed to open custom CA bundle PEM file\ncaused by: open C:\\Users\\<USER>\\Documents\\RootCert.pem: The system cannot find the file specified.\n"
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks!

[Gossamer3 Documentation](https://github.com/GESkunkworks/gossamer3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. Actually while setting up the AWS CLI and Gossamer3, somehow one env variable `AWS_CA_BUNDLE` was set in the Windows environment variables. Which I removed and it worked.

If you look at the error, It is expecting the Root_Cert.pem file to be present in the Documents folder which is not present and therefore it's throwing that error.

[image]